# UICollectionView Or UIButtons

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have a quick question, related to if these images of apps, uses UICollectionView or buttons in their design:

[image]

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely buttons, as UICollectionView is only compatible with iOS 6+

The LinkedIn iOS app only requires iOS 4.3+ so it is not using a UICollectionView-- they most likely built a custom view using UIButtons

Most apps out there still want to support at least iOS 5+ so your not going to see many using the UICollectionView yet.

Here are some open source "Collection View" classes that may fit your need (just make sure they also support old iOS versions)
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=collectionview

Comment: No problem-- good luck building your app!